# Em qual timezone o StackOverflow em Português deveria se basear?

Tags: debate

Ao acessar o link [Melhores analistas de hoje](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) pode se notar que antes da meia-noite o sistema já reiniciou a contagem. Não seria interessante se basear no `timezone` do Brasil (GMT - 3:00)? Sei que o fato de ser em português envolve outros países, mas qual deveria ser o `timezone` oficial do StackOverflow em Português?

Answer (score 17):

Eu não vejo por que não ser UTC como nos demais sites da rede, e você mesmo já deu um bom motivo: o site não é só para o Brasil. E mesmo que fosse, seria para brasileiros, que podem estar em qualquer lugar do mundo, em qualquer fuso horário.

Comment: Até pelo fato de que provavelmente escolheram UTC como referência "global" de tempo, visto que não está favorecendo nem a base da SE, que é essencialmente norteamericana.

Comment: Na verdade é o timezone do Jon Skeet (é sério!)

Comment: Então não foi nem escolha da SE, o próprio sistema quis se comportar assim! :)

Comment: Acho que não faz muito sentido o fato de ser "melhores de hoje" se após ás 21h é resetado o contador, não acha? Para a pessoa que entra ás 22h o contador estaria mentido, ou não está claro.

Comment: Acho que o certo seria mostrar o timezone por usuário, na sua conta você identificaria sua timezone, ou o sistema alterar a descrição, porque o dia não acabou e a informação apresentada não condiz com a descrição.

Comment: @PauloMaciel Eu entendo que isso possa ser mais agradável, mas o benefício de mudar simplesmente não vale o custo. O sistema considera que o dia começa às 0:00 UTC, e usa esse referencial para todos os usuários; isso permite o uso de cache de vários dados, incluindo os que você cita na pergunta.

Comment: @bfavaretto mesmo que não seja interessante a mudança do timezone, a forma como é informado está equivocada, pois não tem semântica com o que é de fato. Eu sempre achei que o "melhores analistas do dia" fazia referência ao dia e não até às 21h. Imagine uma lanchonete no Brasil que atende o dia todo e ao chegar lá eles fecharam às 21h porque estão utilizando o horário de um país da Europa. Se a informação não faz sentido, deveria ser alterada para evitar confusão.

Comment: @PauloMaciel Você tem alguma sugestão alternativa de texto para isso? O texto o nosso moderador poderia alterar, mas a maneira como o sistema funciona eu duvido muito que mude.

Comment: @PauloMaciel Adicionar uma preferência de time-zone teria o potencial de transformar a lista de melhores analistas do dia diferente para usuários em fusos diferentes. Manter o padrão como UTC para toda a rede é a melhor forma de garantir uniformidade dos dados e estatísticas no site.

Comment: @Gabe concordo que essa alteração afetaria todo o sistema, mas penso que pelo menos o texto deveria ser mais claro em relação ao dia estar baseado no UTC+0, assim o usuário não se equivocaria. Não tenho ideia de como poderia ser explicado isso, apenas estou apontando uma informação que está em conflito com o que é mostrado.

Comment: @PauloMaciel "Melhores Analistas nas últimas 24hrs" talvez resolva, mas é loooooongo

Comment: @PauloMaciel O conflito desaparece no momento em que se compreende que o dia para o sistema começa às 0:00 UTC. Inclusive, se você clicar naquele ícone de barrinhas no topo do site, verá que ele mostra o horário UTC entre outras informações. Eu pensei bastante num texto que poderia servir, mas não achei nada que prestasse. Somos todos programadores aqui, acho que conseguimos conviver bem com a noção de "horário do sistema".

Comment: @Gabe realmente é difícil achar um texto simples e claro hahaha

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu morreria e não perceberia isso, acho que essa informação do horário deveria ficar mais visível, principalmente na página de "melhores analistas do dia"

Comment: @PauloMaciel Talvez embaixo da lista de usuários do "hoje" poderia existir uma nota, em letra miúda, dizendo que o sistema usa UTC.

Comment: @bfavaretto acho que seria bem útil uma nota deste tipo, concordo com sua ideia

Comment: Lembrando que o Brasil tem 3 fusos, e temos Portugal, Angola etc...

Comment: Que eu saiba o fuso horário oficial do brasil é o de brasília, eu acho que o padrão deveria ser o brasil, pois é o maior país da américa do sul, e foi os portugueses que roubaram o brasil dos índios. kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk