# Sugestão para informar o time-zone em análises

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-recusado, localização

Com base nessa [questão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1229/em-qual-timezone-o-stackoverflow-em-portugues-deveria-se-basear) que eu havia levantado a um tempo atrás, sugiro que adicione a informação referente ao *time-zone* utilizado no stackoverflow na área de [Estatísticas de Análises](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) (todos os tipos de análises) para não haver confusão.

Minha sugestão é informar "**Horário em UTC**" logo ao lado da palavra "**Hoje**", veja abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só para constar: *time zone* é fuso horário ou zona horária em português.